# Azure Managed Identity - Function App & Storage Account - DefaultAzureCredential fails but ManagedIdentityCredential succeeds

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, identity-management

I want to use user assigned identities for managing access between my resources. I have created an identity which has access the following roles for my storage account:

```
Storage Blob Data Owner
Storage Account Contributor
Storage Table Data Contributor
Storage Queue Data Contributor
```

I am writing this change in C#. When I use

```
var tableUri = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}.table.core.windows.net/", storageAccountName));
var credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential(storageAccessClientId);
services.AddScoped(x => new TableServiceClient(tableUri, credential));
```

Everything works fine, I can access my table without any issue.

**the problem** is that I need to use `DefaultAzureCredential()` for my use case to avoid needing to pass down the `storageAccessClientId` environment variable. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-dotnet#defaultazurecredential), this should work without any issue since it's supposed to go through a chain of permissions till it finds the right one. It does not.

Clearly I have the identity correctly configured since I can access it **if I explicitly tell Azure what ID to use**, but when it attempts this on it's own, it fails and I have spent days now trying to understand why.

One thought I have is that, for some sort of azure behind the scenes magic, it says I need to set AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, and AZURE_TENANT_ID. Is it possible that it's ignoring my User Assigned Managed Identities and just grabbing the AZURE_CLIENT_ID variable?

I think I found my answer and if this is still the case in 2022, then it truly indicates a sad state of Azure. [This](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8037) and [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/11400#issuecomment-620179175) are github issues where Azure devs specifically say that their IAM system is not sophisticated enough to find the user assigned permissions attached to the existing resource unless you *explicitly* state what you want. Coming from AWS this seems completely unacceptable, and I am hoping that this is another case of "azure keeps a lot of old documentation around, so keep looking for the newest truth".. but from everything I've tried it seems that this is actually how it works.

If anyone can show me differently, please let me know because I do not want to use System Managed Identities unless absolutely necessary. (Another SO ticket for that coming...)

Comment: do you by any chance have more than one identity assigned to the Function app? (or enabled both, user- and system-managed?

Comment: I did have multiple identities assigned to the function App. I also had set the AZURE_CLIENT_ID env variable which I realized at some point was getting grabbed by default, but if I removed that to only use my managed identities, i got an "Environment not configured" error

Comment: the github issue that you linked (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/11400) seems to pretty clearly explain the behavior, so I'm not sure what else you are looking for?

Comment: was just looking for hope that since they had two years to improve this functionality, that they would have to get it on par with AWS, and I had just missed the updated documentation for how to accomplish that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure does not provide functionality to handle multiple assigned identities dynamically. You need to help it along by telling it exactly what identity to use in each situation that you would like to use an Identity attached to your service (functiona app, web app, etc)

This was not acceptable for our needs, since we wanted dynamic identity access, so we stopped going down this route and opted for connection strings instead, sadly